# what's wrong in this ado.net code?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

my idea is to check if table has a row then update the current row else if table has no rows then insert a new row, but i got an error (No data exist for the row/column) at line (If IsDBNull(dr(0)) Then)

```
        Try
        Dim sql As String = "select * from tblsetting"
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If IsDBNull(dr(0)) Then
            Dim conn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
            Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
            conn1.Open()
            cmd1.Connection = conn1
            cmd1.CommandText = "insert into tblsetting (f1,f2,f3) values ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', '" & ComboBox3.Text & "')"
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.Dispose()
            conn1.Close()
        Else
            Dim conn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
            Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
            conn1.Open()
            cmd1.Connection = conn1
            cmd1.CommandText = "update tblsetting set f1 ='" & ComboBox1.Text & "', f2 = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', f3 = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' "
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.Dispose()
            conn1.Close()
        End If
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score -1):

i solved this by change the line

```
If IsDBNull(dr(0)) Then
```

To:

```
If dr.HasRows = False Then
```